# Mybatis select statement mapping with multiple inputs

Tags: mybatis

The project is spring-mybatis.I use the @Param annotation,but the value can't pass to it.

Using the following interface

```
findPage(@Param("start") Integer start, @Param("pageSize") Integer pageSize, @Param("delFlag") Integer delFlag);
```

the implement

```
findPage(@Param("start") Integer start, @Param("pageSize") Integer pageSize,@Param("delFlag")Integer delFlag) {
    return this.getSqlSession().selectList(getNs() + ".findPage");
}
```

mapper

```
<select id="findPage" parameterType="map" resultMap="sysUserRM">
SELECT
    *
FROM
    sys_user
WHERE
    del_falg = #{delFlag,jdbcType=INTEGER}
LIMIT #{start,jdbcType=INTEGER},#{pageSize,jdbcType=INTEGER}
```

errors

```
### Error querying database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE
        del_falg = null
    LIMIT null,null' at line 6
```

why it can't receive the inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get your params names passed to the mybatis executor, you must no write your own implementation of the mapper interface but let mybatis generate a proxy using:

```
YourMapper yourMapper = this.getSqlSession().getMapper(YourMapper.class);
YourPage yourPage = yourMapper.findPage(....);
```